# Understanding memory parameters for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jvm

I just installed [Eclipse 4.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Juno) on Linux 64 bit. I have looked at several `Eclipse.ini` threads on Stack Overflow, but I still don't understand the relationship between the different memory parameters.

On one hand, there are parameters that are for the [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine#Process_virtual_machines) and that go under `-vmargs` (for example, `-Xms` and `-Xmx`, `-XX`), while others (for example, `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize`) are provided to Eclipse directly.

What is the relationship between these parameters? How would I set them up for a machine with more than 8 GB of memory?

I am aware of the long Stack Overflow question *[What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)*, but I would like to **learn** how to adjust these parameters myself.

For reference, after installation, the default parameters that Juno has are:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are running Eclipse on an Oracle/Sun JVM, I would disregard `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize` (I personally remove it) and concentrate on `-XX:MaxPermSize`, `-Xms` and `-Xmx`.

The reason for `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize` is that some non-Oracle/Sun JVMs would choke on `-XX:MaxPermSize`. The launcher is programmed to detect the JVM and conditionally supply `-XX:MaxPermSize`. This of course is defeated by the explicit `-XX:MaxPermSize` setting in the default **eclipse.ini** file. That looks like a bug.

I never mess with `-Xms` setting. I set `-Xmx1024m` and `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`.

Comment: It is not an explanation what MaxPermSize parameter mean

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, it should be noted that the permanent generation (PermGen) was replaced with MetaSpace in Java 8 HotSpot.

So, if you're using an Oracle JVM with Java 8 or higher you don't have to worry about these parameters anymore and can safely remove those from you eclipse.ini:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
-XX:MaxPermSize
```

Since then the `-XX:MaxPermSize` parameter is ignored by the JVM and generates a warning (See: [PermGen elimination in JDK 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8)).