# Eclipse internal error

Tags: eclipse

Today when i started my eclipse it gave me following error:

```
org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.parser.JSPSourceParser: 
input could not be parsed correctly at position 150449
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Then it shows another error

```
An internal error occurred during: 
"JSP Index Manager: Processing Resource Events".
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

and then show the error and when i click on yes button it close the eclipse,
I am using eclipse indigo, can any one help please.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how to solve your problem, but I find the recursive nature of the error message very amusing.

Comment: Yes, i also can not under stand this, i got this error many times before, but it did not appear after one restart, but this time... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most typical reason for this error is that Eclipse or its part (e.g. source code parser) ran out of memory. To increase the memory, add/change the following parameters in eclipse.ini. Depending on your machine memory, increase them 4x, even 8x:

-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xss2m -Xms128m -Xmx512m

You can also use these parameters as eclipse command line parameters.
See details, for example, here: [Understanding memory parameters for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864732/understanding-memory-parameters-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

If memory changes in .ini does no do the trick , best way will be to  close any other applications running , after that open Task Manager , and close JAVA services running . Restart the eclipse . NOTE :- This will close the programs using Java if they are open .